# ICMP No Reply Found Issue

Tags: wireshark, icmp

Currently working on a Go based NAT router and when translating ICMP traffic and am seeing some interesting behavior.

The clients request is forwarded to the server, the server keeps track of the internal IP and the clients ICMP ID, uses an open ICMP ID from the server, changes fields in the packet and forwards it to the external address (in this case 8.8.8.8).

When the server receives the response it looks up what internal IP, MAC, and ICMP ID to the external ICMP packet ID and forwards it back to the client.

I am likely missing something basic because I am too close to the issue but any help would be appreciated. If the packet is malformed in some way that I have not recognized then I will be able to adjust the code accordingly.

Request sent from client
 [image: Request sent from client]

Reply Sent from server after receiving outside reply

[image: Reply Sent from server]

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here. You can ask about programming on [so], where there are many network-savvy programmers. The only thing I can see is that your return IP packet may have a bad checksum, and that would cause the destination to drop it (technically, the router should not forward a packet with a bad checksum)..

Comment: My question is in regards to purely the pcap supplied I was simply giving context. The checksum should be recalculated on each packet being sent so that should not be an issue. If you would like me to move the topic I can but I am asking a networking question currently not a programming question.

Comment: Unfortunately, your network device (a router you are building) is off-topic here, as are questions about what your host/server does. You really will not find anyone here to answer the question beyond what I have already said in my comments, and the "should" you postulate for the recalculation cannot be determined as you have the validation disabled in the second screenshot. In any case, using an on-topic, enterprise-grade router would perform properly unless there is an off-topic host problem.

Comment: I am only looking for a second opinion on a PCAP sample provided nothing else, if you would like me to state that explicitly I can but I don't understand why the pure mention of it being being sent from a home-brewed product is action for removing. I am not asking on how to fix the server or the host in any way, purely if there is a red flag in the PCAPs provided. If you would like to continue the conversation regarding the checksum portion of my network question then please unlock the post as it is a networking question and answer.

Comment: I am simply trying to point you to a place where you will get some action on your question. Your question will just languish here, and nobody will answer it. That is not what you want, and it is not what the community here wants. Remember that, "_NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment._"

Comment: Where is the appropriate section to post a question regarding a packet capture.

Comment: I am not an expert on every SE site, and there is not a site for every question. Personally, if I was trying to debug the code on my homegrown router, I would ask on [so], as I have already explained. There are many network-savvy programmers there.

Comment: Look I'll stop arguing with you, I understand where you are coming from but as I have stated numerous times I am simply looking for a second pair of eyes at a PCAP and the section dedicated to network engineering is the most relevant in my eyes. I offered to edit the post to conform to the sections guidelines as well. Have a good day. I am not looking for debugging help in any way.

Comment: @ronMaupin I also think this would be on-topic because he's asking why the ICMP reply is not considered an ICMP reply by Wireshark (which _probably_ means it violates an RFC.

Comment: @DarrellRoot, that would be because his homemade router is doing something wrong, but that is off-topic here, and we cannot help with that.

Comment: ANSWER @cajenh  According to ICMP RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792 top of page 15 **The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo reply message.** Your ICMP request has 48 bytes of data.  Your ICMP reply does not carry any data.

Comment: @DarrellRoot thank you for answering my networking question

Comment: @cajenh Note that most other ICMP types (such as ICMP redirect, ICMP source quench) require IP header plus 64 bits of original data in the reply (per RFC792).  ICMP echo-reply appears to require all of it.  Keep that in mind when dealing with all the ICMP cases.